# Laravel 5.5 Filter on Pivot Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

My Request URL :

http://localhost:8000/api/get-filter-places/z/11,18

No problem query

```
$kitchen = $request->kitchen;

    $places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
            $q->whereIn('eat_category_id', [11,18]);
        })->get();
```

When I write $ kitchen instead of 11,18, it only works as 11.

My Model :

```
public function eatCategories(){
    return $this -> belongsToMany('App\EatCategory', 'eat_category_pivots');
}
```

This is not working :

```
$kitchen = $request->kitchen;

$places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
    ->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
        $q->whereIn('eat_category_id', [$kitchen]);
})->get();
```

Comment: How do your models and relations look? You can add pivot data in your relation definition

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/get-filter-places/z/11,18 it is not  a valid url

Comment: because Im working localhost this is example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delimiter `|` like this `http://localhost:8000/api/get-filter-places/z/11|18`
Try this:

```
        $kitchen = explode('|', $request->kitchen);

        $places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
            ->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
                $q->whereIn('eat_category_id', $kitchen);
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code to:

```
$q->whereIn('eat_categories.id', $kitchen);
```

Also, you need to use a different character like `.` instead of `,` in URL to make it work:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/get-filter-places/z/11.18
```

Then just use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert the string to an array:

```
$kitchen = explode('.', $request->kitchen);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `places` where `name` like %z% and exists (select * from `eat_categories` inner join `eat_category_pivots` on `eat_categories`.`id` = `eat_category_pivots`.`eat_category_id` where `places`.`id` = `eat_category_pivots`.`place_id` and `id` in (18)))

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way.

```
$kitchen = $request->kitchen;

        $kitchen = explode(',', $request->kitchen);


        $places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
            ->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
                $q->whereIn('eat_category_id', $kitchen);
            })->get();
```

Comment: So, the `explode` solution I gave you has nothing to do with your `explode` solution and you solved this by yourself, right? And you've accepted the answer of a guy who simply copied the same `explode` solution and just changed `.` to another symbol `|`.

Comment: yes the problem is that I do not write. [$kitchen] :) correct code $kitchen

Comment: No, it's not. `whereIn` will not work with a string, so the solution is `explode`. If it's not `explode`, then why did you include it in the answer?

Comment: I did not add into the answer.Please review the examples I gave you

Comment: You do not have `explode` in your question and you have it in this answer.